# Numerically stable algorithm for solving the quadratic equation when $a$ is very small or $0$

Tags: numerical-methods, quadratics

Solving $a x^2 + bx +c=0$ for $x$ gives

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \text{, for } a \ne 0$$

But for $a = 0$ we get

$$x=-\frac{c}{b}$$

How to implement a numerically stable algorithm for computing $x$ from $a,b,c$ that *allows $a$ to be close to zero or zero*?

Comment: Look at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Qdrtcs.pdf. Numerics aside, the exact solution can be extremely sensitive to small variations. Take $a=1, b=0$ and $c<0$ close to zero. Then the solutions are $\pm \sqrt{c}$ which is very sensitive for small $c$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes the **Citardauq Formula**
$$x=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$$
can be useful.  One chooses the sign that gives no cancellation in the denominator.

Comment: That's a nice way to generalize a quadratic to the $a=0$ case.  Do you know of a similar version for cubics?

Comment: No, in any case cubics are hopelessly unpleasant by "formula." Though I once made some consulting money by using the Vieta trigonometric solution in an honest to goodness application.

Answer (score 38):

The previous answers correctly identify that there are two quadratic formulas, and that each has a different range of numeric stability; however, they miss the other subtle instabilities.

**To recap**: the standard quadratic formula,
\begin{align*}
  x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}}{2\,a},
\end{align*}
is not unique. A second formula can be generated by multiplying the
numerator and denominator by the "conjugate" of the numerator, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
  x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}}{2\,a}\times\frac{-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}}{-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}}= \frac{2\,c}{-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}},
\end{align*}
where $\mp=-(\pm)$. These two expressions are *analytically* equivalent; however, each is *numerically* unstable for certain values of the
coefficients.

The instability discussed by the other posts is if the term, $4\,a\,c$, is small compared to $b^2$ *and* the sign of the radical term and $b$ are
the same, then [catastropic cancellation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920525/why-is-catastrophic-cancellation-called-so) occurs.

Fortunately, the two quadratic formulas have opposite signs on the radical term for
the same roots, thus it is possible to avoid catastrophic cancellation
by selecting the stable form. I.e.,

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{-b-{\rm sign}(b)\sqrt{b^2-4\,a\,c}}{2a}& x_2 = \frac{c}{a\,x_1}
\end{align*}

For completeness, there are at least three other numerical
instabilities in this formula:

1. **When $a=0$**: thus the equation is linear and has *at most* one root given by $-c/b$. It should be noted that if $b=0$ as well, the equation is actually $c=0$ and leaves $x$ undefined/unconstrained!
2. **When $a\neq0$ and $c=0$**: thus one root is at $x=0$. In this case, the second form of the quadratic equation will yield a NaN ($0/0$) for the second root. It is best therefore to determine the second root by factoring out the root at zero to give $-b/a$.
3. **Overflow**: the floating point representation might over/under-flow during calculation and this is most critical for the $b$ coefficient.  Defining $\mathcal{R}_{max}$ as the largest representable floating point number ($\approx1.8\times10^{308}$ for double precision) then $b^2$ will overflow to infinity at $|b|>\sqrt{\mathcal{R}_{max}}$ according to the IEEE 754 specification (which is "only" $\approx1.304\times10^{154}$). You might not define this as an instability, more an out of range error, but I think the reduced upper range of $b$ is surprising and certainly caught me out!
4. **??**: I'm pretty sure I've missed some more, floating point arithmetic can be very subtle.

I have written a compile-time algebra library and you can take a look at my implementation of the [quadratic formula](https://github.com/toastedcrumpets/stator/blob/f68de3ea091f21bbe6e36feab4e53bdf2ace868d/stator/symbolic/polynomial.hpp#L1053). Below it is a "more-stable" implementation of the cubic formula, shamelessly stolen from D. Herbison-Evans. For higher-order polynomials I rely on bisection techniques based around Budan's theorem which isn't nearly as difficult to make stable!

Comment: This is an excellent answer that answered many of my questions. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very good answer, and the code was useful. I used it for making my [Rust implementation](https://github.com/linebender/kurbo/pull/59) more stable. Let me add if I may a few tips.

First, the division by $a$ might overflow. Thus, instead of checking for $0$, I do the division and check finiteness (this will be a theme). Similarly, while $b^2$ is the most likely reason for arg to overflow, it is not the only one. Thus, I also calculate that and check for finiteness. Finally, there's a chance $c/ax_1$ could fail, so I check that too.

Comment: $x_2$ should not be computed from $x_1$, as that chains inaccuracies. Instead, let $u=-b-\text{sgn}(b)\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}$ and compute $x_1=u/(2a), x_2=2c/u$, as per [this similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4000145). This additionally makes the connection with the citardauq ('quadratic' backward) formula, currently unstated, clear.

Answer (score 3):

Note that only for one from $x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x_2\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ you do "close subtraction", so you can calculate one of them and the second using Viete'a furmula: $x_1 x_2=\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate, why only one of those roots causes a problem?

Comment: subtraction of values that are close to each other destroys numeric accuracy. if $b$ is positive and $b^2 >> 4ac$ then $x_2$ subtracts two numbers very close to each other; if $b$ is negative and $b^2 >> 4ac$ then $x_1$ subtracts two numbers very close to each other.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, where I am looking for a solution that avoids to divide by `a`.

Comment: True, but it’s a good answer to half the question, namely when a ≈ 0. I, too, need a formula (or code) which goes smoothly through a=0, but I can see this being useful on another day. Upvoted (to be clear, I also upvoted the right answer).