# solve a quadratic equation using normalized floating point numbers.

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I googled for about 1 month on a topic of floating point numbers but didn't find what i want ...
I need to know how to solve a quadratic equation using normalized floating point numbers.

Can anyone please explain it in detail with an example of quadratic equation.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest to give a concrete example that you are trying to solve, and show what you have tried so far for that - in that case, we could better understand how to help.

Comment: Thanks yujie..  i was trying to solve this question "find the solution of quadratic equation x² - 1000x + 25 using normalized floating point numbers." I really don't know how to solve it because i tried to learn these type of problems but didn't find any appropriate tutorial.   Please help...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920553/115115 with an example in the second half that is similar to your equation. And also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/866331/115115

Comment: Hello lutzl... I saw your answer . It was very helpful. But i have some doubts about "using normalized floating point numbers " to solve a quadratic equation. can you please explain it in more details so that i easily understand how to solve it. And again thanks for your answer...