# taking coefficient of highest order term zero in a polynomial and solving it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The solutions of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$  are  $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. If we take the coefficient of x i.e $b$ as zero in the equation and also in solution, then we get the same value of x in both cases but If we take $a$ as zero then we don't get same value of x. Is there any way to get the result from the solution when the coefficient of highest order term is zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $a=0$ the initial equation becomes $bx+c=0$ with the solution $x=-c/b$. Obviously if you try to get $a=0$ in the equations for the roots you get $0/0$. However, you can approximate in the limit of small $a$:
$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{b\left(-1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{4ac}{b^2}}\right)}{2a}\approx\frac{b}{2a}\left(-1\pm\left(1-\frac{2ac}{b^2}\right)\right)$$
The solution with "-" will go to $\pm\infty$, depending on the sign of $b$. But the solution with "+" is going to be $$\frac{b}{2a}\frac{-2ac}{b^2}=-\frac{c}{b}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is using the formula $\frac{2c}{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$ instead. You get that formula if you set $x=1/y$ and solve the quadratic equation obtained by clearing denominators in $a\frac{1}{y^2}+b\frac1y + c =0$.

See also the answers to [Numerically stable algorithm for solving the quadratic equation when $a$ is very small or $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866331/).

Answer (score 0):

If a=0 ,the quadratic formula is meaningless because of the a=0 in the  denominator . And the equation is not quadratic ,it is linear .